# WebView support for FlutterWeb for plugin development

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, dart-html, dart-webui

Hi I developed a Flutter Plugin [flutter_tex](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tex). It's based on the WebView. How do I add Flutter Web support for this??

I tried this example to show my HTML content.

```dart
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

  void forWeb() {
    if(kIsWeb){
      // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
      ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
          'hello-world-html',
              (int viewId) => uni_html.IFrameElement()
            ..width = '640'
            ..height = '360'
            ..src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/IyFZznAk69U'
            ..style.border = 'none');

      Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        child: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            child: HtmlElementView(viewType: 'hello-world-html'),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

But this code is fine when building for the web but when for compiling on android I get this error even if I am not calling above code.

```
Compiler message:
../lib/flutter_tex.dart:139:10: Error: Getter not found: 'platformViewRegistry'.
      ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can copy paste run 3 files below `main.dart` , `mobileui.dart` and `webui.dart` 
You can put `mobile` and `web` code in different files and use conditional import 
This allow you to have different implement on mobile and web

```
import 'mobileui.dart' if (dart.library.html) 'webui.dart' as multiPlatform;
...
home:  multiPlatform.TestPlugin(),
```

working demo 
when run with `Chrome` or `Android Emulator` in `Android Studio`

[image]
[image]

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'mobileui.dart' if (dart.library.html) 'webui.dart' as multiPlatform;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget { 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(        
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home:  multiPlatform.TestPlugin(),
    );
  }
}
```

mobileui.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPlugin extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestPluginState createState() => _TestPluginState();
}

class _TestPluginState extends State<TestPlugin> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("Mobile");
  }
}
```

webui.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'dart:js' as js;
import 'dart:ui' as ui;


class TestPlugin extends StatefulWidget {
  TestPlugin();

  _TestPluginState createState() => _TestPluginState();
}

class _TestPluginState extends State<TestPlugin> {
  String createdViewId = 'map_element';

  @override
  void initState() {
    // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
        createdViewId,
            (int viewId) => html.IFrameElement()
          ..width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.toString() //'800'
          ..height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.toString() //'400'
          ..srcdoc = """<!DOCTYPE html><html>
          <head><title>Page Title</title></head><body><h1>This is a Heading</h1><p>This is a paragraph.</p></body></html>"""            
          ..style.border = 'none');

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[300], width: 1),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        child: Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            child: HtmlElementView(
              viewType: createdViewId,
            )));
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a great favor.

Comment: @chunhunghan i got this error ```The name 'platformViewRegistry' is being referenced through the prefix 'ui', but it isn't defined in any of the libraries imported using that prefix.``` and this is my flutter doctor ```Flutter (Channel beta, 1.22.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.508], locale en-US)```

Comment: @Reign, please reference this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41563