# Flutter Webview not working for Flutter web

Tags: flutter-web

I am trying to show a webpage in `webview` via URL.
I have tried `flutter_webview_plugin` plugin but it was not working when I run the project on the browser.

Is there any another way to show the webpage in the flutter web application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

flutter_webview_plugin is to embed web pages inside an app. In flutter web you should use `HtmlElementView` widget. 
Most demos out there use `IFrameElement` to embed a webpage. You can check this [easy_web_view](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_web_view) package for handling both mobile and web platform automatically. 
It internally uses `HTMLElementView` and `WebView` automatically depending on the case of the deployment.

some example is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60075516/webview-support-for-flutterweb-for-plugin-development)

**Update for adding onLoad listener**

```dart
IFrameElement iframeElement = IFrameElement()
      ..src = 'url'
      ..style.border = 'none'
      ..onLoad.listen((event) {
        // perform you logic here.
      });

    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'webpage',
      (int viewId) => iframeElement,
    );

    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      child: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          child: HtmlElementView(viewType: 'webpage'),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: How can i get PageLoadComplete callback from this library.

Comment: If you need that, then you should go with `HtmlElementView` widget and use the `onLoad` stream of the `IFrameElement` from `dart:html`. You can see the docs [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.0/dart-html/Element/onLoad.html). This is an EventStream which you can listen and do the logic you need inside the callback.

Comment: thak u sir for help, I have completed that code using HtmlEventView but i dont undersand where to add callback for PageLoad complete event,

ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
        'webpage',
        (int viewId) => IFrameElement()
          ..src = url
          ..style.border = 'none');
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      child: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: double.infinity,
          height:  double.infinity,
          child: HtmlElementView(
              viewType: 'webpage'),
        ),
      ),
    );

Comment: Error: PlatformException(Unregistered factory, No factory registered for viewtype 'map_element', null, null)   this error occurred

Answer (score 4):

if someone facing issue loading mobile side then go with this, its works in Flutter Android, Ios, Web :-

```
EasyWebView(
        height: 400,
        width: 1000,
        isHtml: false, // Use Html syntax
        isMarkdown: false, // Use markdown syntax
        convertToWidgets: true,
        src: Uri.dataFromString('<html><body><iframe allow="camera *;microphone *" height="100%" width="100%"'
            ' frameborder="0" src="$url"></iframe></body></html>', mimeType: 'text/html').toString(),
      ),
```

you guys can use any webview to load any web page in your web/app in flutter using Url in html just change src = "$url" :)

Comment: it is not available for dart null safe version.

Comment: rn, it is not working with Web, issue link: [link](https://github.com/rodydavis/easy_web_view/issues/81)

Answer (score 0):

## Answer for 2023

The [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview/versions/6.0.0-beta.22) package just added support for the web!

You can read the [web setup instructions](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/intro/#setup-web) in the official Flutter InappWebView docs but to summarize:

### 1. Add script to

```
<head>
  <!-- ... -->
    <script type="application/javascript" src="/assets/packages/flutter_inappwebview/assets/web/web_support.js" defer></script>
  <!-- ... -->
</head>
```

### 2. Use the InAppWebView Widget

```
Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: InAppWebView(
        initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url:WebUri('https://flutter.dev/')),
       )
    )
);
```

Note that there are some restrictions on what can be done in a WebView an Flutter web but for simply displaying content, this should work.