# How to render a local HTML file with flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm aware of [webview](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) package but it only supports ios and android but not flutter web.
Are there any other options than that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Webview not working for Flutter web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61499763/flutter-webview-not-working-for-flutter-web)

Comment: It does, thank you!