# Flutter - dart.ui no method 'platformViewRegistry'

Tags: html, flutter, dart, webview

Im working on Flutter web and I want to render an html code. Since flutter_webview_plugin doesnt support flutter web yet Im using IFrameElement and HtmlElementView. But I have this problem when using dart.ui, `platformViewRegistry` method isn't defined.

Error message:

> The name 'platformViewRegistry' is being referenced through the prefix 'ui', but it isn't defined in any of the libraries imported using that prefix.

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
......
 ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
        createdViewId,
            (int viewId) => html.IFrameElement()
          ..width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.toString() //'800'
          ..height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.toString() //'400'
          ..srcdoc = """<!DOCTYPE html><html>
          <head><title>Page Title</title></head><body><h1>This is a Heading</h1><p>This is a paragraph.</p></body></html>"""            
          ..style.border = 'none');
```

Example Code From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60089273/12789200

I read some solution to solve this problem. But I don't want to downgrade my flutter version. Since in the past month Flutter has a lot of changes

Flutter Doctor

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.22.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.508], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.49.3)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
```

Is there any other solution for this problem? Or another example I can used for WebView on Flutter Web.

Answer (score 2):

Up to my knowledge I have tried several solutions and apparently there is a problem in the `'dart:ui'` package .
The solutions I've tried are:

1. Tried using a WebView widget *//Failed No web support yet*
2. Tried rendering on  HTML instead of CanvasKit *//UI will look rubbish*
3. Tried editing on the `**analysis_options.yaml**`
4. Tried adding a comment above the code that said `//ignore: undefined_prefixed_name`

All these solutions referred to other errors, the solution was to use a package called:
universal_ui from the https://pub.dev/packages/universal_ui , which is apparently the same as `'dart:ui'` package, but with all methods included.
Hope this works for you !

Comment: universal_ui isn't null safe, wondering what you're using if you're now null safe in your project.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a new API that solves the error:

```dart
import 'dart:ui_web' as ui_web; // New import for all web-only stuff...

...

ui_web.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(...);
```

Ref: https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/41877