# Flutter How to download a file from an url without any third party library

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have a download URL of a file. Now I want to download the file and retrieve it.

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you just ask a question and immediately answered it to yourself?

Comment: @isaaaaame There is nothing wrong with that. The point of this site is to *share knowledge*. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @isaaaaame yes folk. I did because I need this solution further and I shared it because it will be great if its help anyone else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can use `Dart` s `HttpClient` class and The implementation will be something like this method given below.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';


  Future<File> _downloadFile(String url, String filename) async {
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    try{
      var request = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
      var response = await request.close();
      var bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
      final dir = await getTemporaryDirectory();//(await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
      File file = new File('${dir.path}/$filename');
      await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
      print('downloaded file path = ${file.path}');
      return file;
    }catch(error){
      print('pdf downloading error = $error');
      return File('');
    }
```

Comment: I did not try it but Dart states that dart:io is not for web apps. https://dart.dev/libraries/dart-io