# Large storage in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, storage, flutter-web, file-storage

Is there a way to store approximately 2GB of binary data (video files with ~600MB each) in Flutter web?
I need to support web on both desktop and mobile devices.

I tried [Localstorage](https://pub.dev/packages/localstorage) (converting everything to `List<int>`), but it caps out at a couple of MB. [Drift](https://pub.dev/packages/drift) seems to be based on Localstorage aswell. Best thing I found was [Sembast](https://pub.dev/packages/sembast_web), which uses IndexedDB, but even there I [seem to be reaching the limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692820/maximum-item-size-in-indexeddb).
Maybe there's a work-around to access the file system?

Edit: I basically want to cache the videos, so they are available offline (so downloading and using FilePicker is not an option). I also considered using assets, but 2GB would be too much to download initially, even if I compress it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To read and Write File in Flutter Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57182634/to-read-and-write-file-in-flutter-web)

Comment: I should clarify: I need this to happen in the background to make the videos available offline, so I don't want the user to download and select files manually.