# Flutter Web how to read and write file (xlsx,txt etc)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, filereader, excel-reader

I am trying to read the two files first one is a text file and the second one is an excel file. I'm using flutter web 2.10 but can't find a way to read those files. I have tried this method but it doesn't work now [To read and Write File in Flutter Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57182634/to-read-and-write-file-in-flutter-web)

Currently, I am kinda stuck with it. For now, I am reading the text file as a string and then parsing it, but it is not a good way to do it. So if you have any better way to read files in flutter web please do share.

```
 Uint8List? bytes=result.files.first.bytes;
 file=File.fromRawPath(bytes!);
 file.readAsLines();
 returnResult=file.toString();
```

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).  [Edit] your question and copy-paste it into the question itself.