# Flutter VideoPlayer from bytes

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

I am trying to build an application in which the backend generates a short video and returns it as a file in the response. In the Flutter frontend i am parsing the response object to get the bytes representing the video. Using these bytes, I would like to create a [Video Player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player).

Here's my question: How can I initialize the `VideoPlayerController` the byte array I received from the response?

According to the docs, `VideoPlayerController.file()` is not working as that would require dart.io which is not available on web. This only leaves me the `network` or `asset` options.

Comment: Look at this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63842948/10078246)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small code implementation of same.

```
class VideoPlayerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Uint8List videoBytes;

  const VideoPlayerWidget({super.key, required this.videoBytes});

  @override
  State<VideoPlayerWidget> createState() => _VideoPlayerWidgetState();
}

class _VideoPlayerWidgetState extends State<VideoPlayerWidget> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  late html.VideoElement _videoElement;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _videoElement = html.VideoElement();

    // Register an event listener to track when the video has loaded
    _videoElement.addEventListener('loaded metadata', (_) {
      _initializeVideoPlayer();
    });

    // Convert the byte array to a blob and set it as the video source
    final blob = html.Blob([widget.videoBytes]);
    final url = html.Url.createObjectUrl(blob);
    _videoElement.src = url;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    _videoElement.pause();
    _videoElement.removeAttribute('src');
    html.Url.revokeObjectUrl(_videoElement.src);
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayer() async {
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(_videoElement.currentSrc!);
    await _controller.initialize();
    await _controller.setLooping(true);
    _controller.play();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
        child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
      );
    } else {
      return Container();
    }
  }
}
```

You can use this widget as

```
final Uint8List videobytes; // initalize your video bytes here
VideoPlayerWidget(videoBytes: videoBytes)
```