# Generate a json file in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, file, flutter-web

I am workin on a flutter web project and I want to generate json configuration files automatically inside the poject devepending on the environment (dev, acc, prod) using envied variables when I run the app.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final file = File('file.json');
  final data = {
    'name': 'Foo',
    'age': 42,
  };
  final content = json.encode(data);
  file.writeAsStringSync(content);
}
```

Comment: Yes but I think dart.io is not supported for web so the data won't be written in the file

Comment: check this out then, maybe the solutions will be of help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57182634/to-read-and-write-file-in-flutter-web

Comment: @Etornam this writes a file by sending the user an auto-download. For my case I want to edit the local file automatically in background.