# How to play a File video on Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, web, local-storage, flutter-video-player

I ave a Flutter app that communicates with a backend python server using websockets. Essentially the app sends a video to the server, the backend does some ML stuff and sends back an mp4 file as a Uint8List. I'm converting that list into a List then creating a temporary File object where I write the data converted. Finally I use this file to play the video with the "video_player" package using the .file method.

```
Future<void> convertListToVideoFileMobile() async {
    final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final tempPath = tempDir.path;

    // Concatenate the Uint8List chunks into a single Uint8List
    final videoData = Uint8List.fromList(
      videoList.fold<List<int>>([], (prev, curr) => prev..addAll(curr)),
    );

    // Create a new File in the temporary directory and write the video data
    final file = File('$tempPath/myVideo.mp4');
    await file.writeAsBytes(videoData);

    videoFileMobile = file;
  }
```

The issue is that getting access to a temporary file using Flutter web is denied following my researches.

So I was wondering is there a way to find an alternative process to make this happen.

I did not try a lot to be honest because i didn't find anything in the web nor in stackoverflow but I'm not losing hope.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read and Write Files in Flutter Web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57182634/how-can-i-read-and-write-files-in-flutter-web)

Answer (score 0):

You can use HtmlElementView.
Html5 audio and video can accept Data URIs as a source.
The result we want([source](https://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/09/html5/html5-media-and-data-uri/)):

```
<video controls>
    <source type="video/webm" src="data:video/webm;base64,GkXfowEAAAAAAAAfQoaBAUL3gQFC8......jVOrhB9DtnVTrIMQTPc=">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="data:video/mp4;base64,AAAAHGZ0eXBtcDQyAAAAAG1wNDJpc29....../l/L+X8v5AAAAMgfDg==">
</video>
```

The implementation example:

```
import 'dart:ui_web' as ui_web;
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class VideoComponent extends StatelessWidget {
  const VideoComponent({
    required this.id,
    required this.bytes,
    required this.minetype,
    super.key,
  });

  // unique id
  final String id;

  // mimetype like video/mp4, video/webm
  final String minetype;

  // video data
  final Uint8List bytes;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final sourceElement = html.SourceElement();
    sourceElement.type = mimeType;
    sourceElement.src = Uri.dataFromBytes(bytes, mimeType: mimeType).toString();

    final videoElement = html.VideoElement();
    videoElement.controls = true;
    videoElement.children = [sourceElement];
    videoElement.style.height = '100%';
    videoElement.style.width = '100%';

    ui_web.platformViewRegistry
        .registerViewFactory(id, (int viewId) => videoElement);

    return HtmlElementView(viewType: id);
  }
}
```