# Flutter store data with 'last modified' information

Tags: database, flutter, dart

My multi-platform flutter app should store data with a timestamp when exactly the data was lastly modified.

My idea was to store the data in files, because of the [File.lastModified](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File/lastModified.html) property.
However it is not possible to store files on web without [nasty workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63842948/7277725).

Are there any other lightweight ways to store data and know when the data was modified?